# When the launchd will register for the events?

Tags: macos, cocoa, launchd

I need to open my application and run a specific task from that application automatically in a given time. So I searched in google and came up with `launchd`. First question, Is this is correct choice?
I have created a plist and I kept that in the location `~/Library/LaunchAgents/fileName.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.companyname.example</string>
    <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>mac_1</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>open</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>Argument_1</string>
        <string>Argument_2</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Day</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>10</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>41</integer>
        <key>Month</key>
        <integer>8</integer>
        <key>Weekday</key>
        <integer>3</integer>

    </dict>
       <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The Problem with this is, It is working only when the computer will restarted, otherwise it will not be invoked. So, My Second question when the launchd will register for the events ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a utility called "launchctl" 
You need to use it to load your plis file into launchd. 
Type: launchctl load plist_file.

If you want to schedule something from your application - one way would be calling "system" to execute launchtl utility. There is also undocumented API for launchd but I couldn't find a way to use it for scheduling.

launchd would be the easiest way to schedule something on the system, as it has reach scheduling properties.

Comment: thank you!! May I know how to launch a specific process from my application while opening?

Comment: Please clarify meaning of "while opening".
there are number of ways to start a process from another one, the easiest way to go is "system" function call.

Comment: While launchd opening my application I want to do a specific process from my app. For example while opening iPhoto it straight away starts exporting.

Comment: What kind of application is that ? native C  with main function as an entry point ? Then you have your answer there, at the beginning of the main. Or, is it a COCOA UI application ? I guess it is, then you need to decide when you want to do extra stuff - look for - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification function or you can use any other classes init function, or try to use awakeFromNib notification.